# Babel and Bluebird promise

Tags: node.js, bluebird, babeljs

By default Babel propose Promise polyfill. How can  I force it to use Bluebird implementation or disable the polyfill (I use preset es2015).

It's easy to forget import Bluebird and accidentally use polyfill implementation.

Comment: I'm confused, is it easy to forget because you are naming your import `Promise`, or just because you get the two mixed up? Babel just makes the environment standard, you'd have the same problem if you loaded no polyfill and were running the code in an environment that already has Promise. It's not really a Babel issue.

Comment: consider a situation: I'm saying something like `let Promise = require('bluebird')`.  But my young colleague just forget to do this. Now he has a Promise which doesn't  have methods like  `spread`

Comment: Totally, but that's a side-effect of allowing shadowing a global variable. I'd generally have a linting rule to disallow that and use `let Bluebird = require('bluebird');` if you need it. Chrome, Firefox, and Node >=0.11 all have a global `Promise` and whether you use Babel or not, it will be there. You can always do `window.Promise = require('bluebird');` at the start of your app, but then you are relying on non-standard behavior and mutating globals, which is not a good idea.

Comment: your ideas sounds reasonable. Thanks. How did you add  the rule? Can you show a code?

Answer (score 5):

I guess this preset should resolve the issue:
[babel-preset-async-to-bluebird](https://github.com/eknkc/babel-preset-async-to-bluebird)

After installing with the usual:

> $ npm install --save-dev babel-preset-async-to-bluebird

The following code using the Node API would enable that preset:

```
require("babel-core").transform("code", {
  presets: ["async-to-bluebird"]
});
```

*<sup>slightly adapted from the readme.md written by [eknkc](https://github.com/eknkc)</sup>*

Comment: You probably should read [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370) to understand why this is such an important issue on all Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: Hi  @PM2Ring. It is nice to send to some general guidelines. But please, read about Babel and concept of presets. Preset is just a set of option. The answer is just set this preset